# get result from Activity using fragment called immediately

Tags: android, launchmode, startactivityforresult

I have `Fragment A in Activity A`. When i start a new `Activity B` using `startActivityForResult` from `Fragment A`. **onActivityResult** called immediately while `Activity B`  has just started.The result code got using **onActivityResult**  correct in `Fragment` but wrong showing in `Activity A`.

I think the problem is due to some **launch mode**. I

```
        <activity
            android:name="xyz.ActivityA"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityA" >
        </activity>
```

And Activity B

```
          <activity android:name=".xyz.ActivityB"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
```

> I simply want to open an Activity using startActivityForResult from fragment and get result from it on selecting a spinner item.

Comment: put your activity code.

Comment: which one Activity A or Activity B?

Comment: activity B.............